# querying for elements that are inside binding helpers

Tags: javascript, html, dom, polymer, shadow-dom

In order to to get Polymer's data-binding without creating a custom element, I am using the "dom-bind" template helper. Later on, I am going to need to access the nodes inside the template so I can use [masonry.js](http://masonry.desandro.com/)
to create a grid out of the data.

Here is the my template that is inside the main document:

```
  <!-- Skills --> 
  <template is="dom-bind" class="careerSkills_consumer projects_consumer" id="resume-container">
    <page-section id="resume">
      <section-title>Skills and Projects</section-title>
      <section-content>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{careerSkills}}">
          <skill-category class="grid-item" title="{{item.header}}" skills="{{item.skills}}"></skill-category>  
        </template>
        <project-showcase class="grid-item" projects="{{projects}}"></project-showcase>
      </section-content>
    </page-section>
  </template>
```

The data itself is provided elsewhere and is irrelevant. The issue I am running into is that both `dom-bind` and `dom-repeat` seem to create local dom and put the result inside of it.

To create my grid, I need to access both the container for the grid, which will be the `section-content` element and the grid items, which are the `skill-category` elements inside the `dom-repeat` template.

If they all resided in the same document, I think could do (I am new to masonry, so this might not actually work):

```
document.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function () {
    $('#resume section-content').masonry({
        columnWidth: $('#resume skill-category')[0],
        itemSelector: 'skill-category',
        isFitWidth: true
    });
});
```

But the queries don't seem to work because presumably the elements I need are hidden away from the main document in the shadow dom.

I was able to get access to the content inside `#resume-container` via:

```
Polymer.dom(document.querySelector('#resume-container')).node.content
```

However, I still can't get to the `skill-category` elements in the `dom-repeat`. This is getting kind of pedantic and I'm not even sure if it will work when masonry tries to do the positioning.

Is there a better way to go about this?

To be clear, this question is about how to properly gain reference to the content distributed inside of template helpers, but I would also appreciate any general advice to using polymer to do this sort of thing, where a custom element isn't exactly what I'm looking for since I'm only going to use the template in one spot and shadow dom is more hassle than help, but I need the data-binding.

Comment: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-change

Comment: @NeilJohnRamal I'm confused. Can you explain how the `dom-change` event helps me?

Comment: The helper elements don't actually use the shadow dom, they're just basically supercharged template elements. You need to listen to their dom-change event in order to access the content that they are producing.

Comment: @NeilJohnRamal Is that the ONLY way? It seems kind of weird to me. Do you know the semantics behind why they don't just stamp the results into the DOM?

Comment: Considering that Polymer's entire binding system is based on events, it's not that weird as you may think. Since these template elements would likely be updating the DOM tree everytime the properties change, it would be more logical to listen to the dom-change event.

Comment: @NeilJohnRamal If template helpers don't use the shadow dom, then shouldn't their results end up in the DOM ?  Is it just that I'm trying to access them to early?

Comment: Yes. And that is the reason why you should listen to the dom-change event.